# Unable to build project using Gradle after upgrading Corda Gradle Plugins Version

Tags: corda

After updating `ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version` in my CorDapp's `build.gradle` file, the project is failing to build.

When running the build from IntelliJ, I get the following error:

> Error:Unable to find method 'kotlin.text.CharsKt.checkRadix(I)I'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

When running the build from the command line using the Gradle wrapper, I get:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'oracle-example'.
>     Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation']
>     Could not create plugin of type 'Cordformation'.
>     Could not initialize class net.corda.plugins.Cordformation

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your Gradle wrapper version.

The easiest way to do this is to overwrite your project's `./gradle` folder with one from a sample project that is using the desired Gradle plugins version (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example).